# Getting HTML from a secure (login) website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, cookies, web

I am currently working on a project that can use the HTML information a certain web page displays.

The thing is, I can't just use WebRequest, because the website I am trying to get HTML from has a login system and the page requires you to be logged in.

However, if it's any matter - the user using my page should have access to this page, he's remembered logged in with cookies.

So my point is, I need a way for my server to have the cookies and read from the web page, or rather, make the client side give me the HTML code it will display him if he enters the page.

I am using ASP.NET with C#.

Comment: what is the question? :)

Comment: "The thing is, I can't just use WebRequest, because the website I am trying to get HTML from has a login system and the page requires you to be logged in." - not true, you can server-side get html even from password protected page, you just have to know username/password; fire on request to login page, remember the cookies and use the cookies in the second request you fire to page you're interested in.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I am asking how to do that, how can I have cookies within the WebRequest?

Comment: @VladimirShmidt My question is, how can I send a WebRequest with cookies, or use the current client to get the HTML the web page would show him, if he entered this website.

Answer (score 0):

I would respond in comments "how to send webrequest with cookies", but since the formatting capabilities of comments are limited, I'll post it as an answer:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Text;

  // ...

  var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:54903/SimpleLogin.ashx") as HttpWebRequest;
  var container = new CookieContainer();
  request.CookieContainer = container;
  string postData = "username=user&password=pass";
  byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  request.ContentLength = data.Length;
  using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  }
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

  request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:54903/Home.ashx") as HttpWebRequest;
  request.CookieContainer = container;
  request.Method = "GET";
  response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  string authorizedGetString;
  using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
      authorizedGetString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
```